# Rails: Implementing multi-step registration processes (with OmniAuth)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, state-machine

I'm trying to implement a multi-step registration process. This particular implementation involves OmniAuth, but for the purposes of this discussion it could well be any OAuth provider.

Here are the registration steps we might implement:

**Step 1.** User *clicks* Connect with ***_*__*_*__*_*__**.

**Step 2.** Authorize via ***_*__*_*__*_*__** and redirect to callback. Pull relevant data from provider and save to your `User` model.

**Step 3.** Pick a username, fill out email address, and any other required data for registering for your app. Also save this to your `User` model.

**The problem** for me lies in the transition from Step 2 to Step 3. **I could** set validations on the data based on state, using something like [**state_machine**](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine), for example.

**However**, I would have to remove not-null constraints at the column level for certain essential pieces of data, like `username` in my case (which is used for user routes), or `email`. I'm not super comfortable removing another layer of data integrity.

I'm sure this problem has been solved a thousand times before. How have you handled it and how would you recommend I handle it?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917604/rails-multi-step-new-user-signup-form-fsm

Comment: @Thilo I've seen that screencast and it doesn't resolve my problem with the not-null constraints, same as with state_machine, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the data from the provider as hidden fields in your form for step 3 to pick username, email address etc?  This way you wouldn't be creating a `User` instance until you had all of the data available.

Comment: To clarify, Step 2 isn't really a form, it's just code executed within a controller. I *could* just render the data in a form with a GET request rather than save it, but I'm not sure how great an idea that is.